# Asp.Net MVC 5 bind parameter exclusively from body

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, model-binding

I want to prevent posting sensitive data via url query string to a MVC 5 application.

In MVC there is a `DefaultModelBinder`. The `DefaultModelBinder` looks for the `ActionMethod` parameters in the url query string, the body and the route. But my target is to bind the parameters exclusively from the body and **not** from route or query string.

In Asp.Net WebApi there is such a concept. The Attribute [FromBody] will do the job: http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/parameter-binding-in-aspnet-web-api

Is there something suitable for MVC?

I´ve found the `System.Web.ModelBinding.FormAttribute` (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.modelbinding.formattribute(v=vs.110).aspx). However, if I decorate the parameter, it has no effect to the model binding.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By default, the binder looks for data in four places: form data, route data, the query string, and any uploaded files.

It is possible to restrict the binding to a single source of data. To do so you should call the **UpdateModel** method passing, as the second parameter, a **FormValueProvider** object( an implementation of **IValueProvider**).

```
public ActionResult Products()
{
    IList<Products> products = new List<Products>();
    UpdateModel(products, new FormValueProvider(ControllerContext));
    return View(products);
}
```

The complete list of objects is (they all receive the ControllerContext as the contructor parameter):

- **FormValueProvider**: search for data in the body (Request.Form)
- **RouteDataValueProvider**: search for data in the route (RouteData.Value)
- **QueryStringValueProvider**: search for data in the query string (Request.QueryString)
- **HttpFileCollectionValueProvider**: search for uploaded files (Request.Files)

Comment: Thank you, that is what I am looking for. I hoped that it could be done via Attribute. But this is also a good solution. By the way I am going to use `TryUpdateModel()`.

Answer (score 5):

Another way: create a **custom model binder** that uses **FormValueProvider**. The advantage of this is that you don't have to modify the action method.

Example:

```
[ModelBinder(typeof(PersonBinder))]
public class Person
{
    [DisplayName("Social Security Number")]
    public int SSN { get; set; }

    [HiddenInput(DisplayValue = false)]
    public string ShouldNotBind { get; set; }
}

public class PersonBinder : IModelBinder
{
    public object BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        bindingContext.ValueProvider = new FormValueProvider(controllerContext);
        Person model = (Person)bindingContext.Model ?? new Person();
        model.SSN = Convert.ToInt16(GetValue(bindingContext, "SSN"));
        return model;
    }

    private string GetValue(ModelBindingContext context, string name)
    {
        ValueProviderResult result = context.ValueProvider.GetValue(name);
        if (result == null || result.AttemptedValue == "")
        {
            return "<Not Specified>";
        }
        return result.AttemptedValue;
    }
}
```

And your action method:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Person(Person person)
{
    return View(person);
}
```

Even if you post with a querystring, the `ShouldNotBind` property will show as "null".

Answer (score -1):

Why not use form's then?
On submit you post form data

Comment: Don´t know exactly what you mean. Asp.Net Web Forms is not a alternative.

Comment: Add -> View. Pick template "edit". Select yours model class. It will autogenerate form for you. You will understand then

Comment: Ok I got it. Of course, this is the way I render the form. Every "normal" user will post the data over the body. But anybody can send a request with parameters in the query string and MVC will bind them. That is the case I would like to prevent.

Comment: make form as POST. Then add attribute [HttpPost] over method. Now it will not be possible to use url

Comment: No, I think that is not correct. Decorating an ActionMethod with `[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]` forces MVC to accept only HttpPost. But you can pass your data still in the query string.

Comment: An user can also forge form and post whatever he likes.... I really doesn;t understand what you are trying to acomplish. [HttpPost] will give you at least that noone will send sensitive data by creating a link

Comment: You can still pass your still in the query string and the model binder will use it if it's not in the body

Comment: But if you want to edit query string in form, they you need to change form action. If somone know how to do that then he also would know how to add <input> with proper name. It really doesn;t matter. Adding HTTPPOST will at least allow to not execute action for GET.