# Controller Parameters Empty Sending ViewModel JSON via AJAX

Tags: c#, jquery, json, ajax, model-view-controller

Im trying to send `PropertyDetails ViewModel` to controller function `SaveDetails`.

I currently serialize the Model using `Newtonsoft.JsonConvert`, which then I use `JSON.Stringify` to convert to a `JSONString`  which then AJAX uses to send the data to the `Controller` but when I place a breakpoint on the controller function `SaveDetails` the object is empty(not null) however the objects inside the `ViewModel` are null.

```
 var json = @Html.Raw(@JsonConvert.SerializeObject(@Model));
 console.log(JSON.stringify(json));

    $.ajax({
        url: "@Url.Action("SaveDetails")",
        type: "POST",
        data: JSON.stringify(json),
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        error: function (response) {
        },
        success: function (response) {
            alert(response);
        }
    });
```

Controller Function SaveDetails

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult SaveDetails(PropertyDetailsViewModel PropertyDetail)
    {
        if(PropertyDetail != null)
        {

           return Json("Success");

        }
        return Json("Failed");

    }
```

CONSOLE.LOG of the JSON.Stringfy(@Model) used JSONLint to check if it was valid JSON and it is.

```js
{
 "PropertyID": 2,
 "PropertyDetail": {
  "AccessInformation": "",
  "AddressLine1": "",
  "AddressLine2": "",
  "AddressLine3": "",
  "AddressLine4": "",
  "AddressLine5": "",
  "BranchID": 1,
  "BuildingType": "",
  "CurrentValue": 0,
  "Description": "",
  "Garages": 0,
  "HouseAlarm": false,
  "LandlordID": "",
  "LastUpdatedTime": "2016-11-20T13:48:59.693",
  "LastUpdatedUser": "mimtiaz",
  "Latitude": 0,
  "LeaseEnd": null,
  "LeaseNotes": " ",
  "LeaseStart": null,
  "Longtitude": 0,
  "MarketingDescription": "",
  "NickName": "",
  "Notes": "",
  "ParentID": 0,
  "ParkingSpaces": 0,
  "Postcode": "",
  "PurchaseDate": null,
  "PurchaseNotes": " ",
  "PurchasePrice": 0,
  "PurchaseType": " ",
  "SaleDate": null,
  "SaleNotes": " ",
  "SalePrice": 0,
  "size": "",
  "SmokeAlarms": 0,
  "Status": "Active",
  "TemplateType": "1",
  "ValuationDate": null,
  "ValuationNotes": " ",
  "YearBuilt": 1900
 },
 "PropertyImages": [{
  "DateAdded": "2016-10-01T00:00:00",
  "Description": "",
  "Filename": "1872_MVR103597_IMG_09_0000_max_476x317.JPG",
  "ID": 1,
  "InventoryID": 0,
  "PropertyID": 2,
  "RoomID": 0,
  "Sequence": 1,
  "TenancyID": 0,
  "Title": "1872_MVR103597_IMG_09_0000_max_476x317.JPG",
  "Type": "P"
 }, {
  "DateAdded": "2016-10-01T00:00:00",
  "Description": "",
  "Filename": "5384_26648557_IMG_26_0000_max_476x317.jpg",
  "ID": 2,
  "InventoryID": 0,
  "PropertyID": 2,
  "RoomID": 0,
  "Sequence": 2,
  "TenancyID": 0,
  "Title": "5384_26648557_IMG_26_0000_max_476x317.jpg",
  "Type": "P"
 }, {
  "DateAdded": "2016-10-01T00:00:00",
  "Description": "",
  "Filename": "39050_6028636_IMG_19_0000_max_476x317.jpg",
  "ID": 3,
  "InventoryID": 0,
  "PropertyID": 2,
  "RoomID": 0,
  "Sequence": 3,
  "TenancyID": 0,
  "Title": "39050_6028636_IMG_19_0000_max_476x317.jpg",
  "Type": "P"
 }],
 "InventoryList": [],
 "PropertyPath": "/Insight/Property 2",
 "SideNavigationViewModel": {
  "DynamicEntities": [{
   "ID": 1,
   "EntityType": "O",
   "EntityLabel": "Solicitor",
   "Parent": "Other",
   "MultiplePerCase": true,
   "DynamicOrgID": 1,
   "OrgFKID": 2,
   "OrgID": "GARNER 003",
   "OrgContactID": "PARTIND001",
   "OrgRef": "",
   "DynamicPersonID": 0,
   "PersonFKID": 0,
   "ThirdPartyID": "",
   "PersonRef": "",
   "SectionHeaderID": 0,
   "EntityName": "Solicitor",
   "AccessLevel": "",
   "LetterFolder": ""
  }, {
   "ID": 2,
   "EntityType": "O",
   "EntityLabel": "Insurance",
   "Parent": "Other",
   "MultiplePerCase": false,
   "DynamicOrgID": 0,
   "OrgFKID": 0,
   "OrgID": "",
   "OrgContactID": "",
   "OrgRef": "",
   "DynamicPersonID": 0,
   "PersonFKID": 0,
   "ThirdPartyID": "",
   "PersonRef": "",
   "SectionHeaderID": 0,
   "EntityName": "Insurance",
   "AccessLevel": "",
   "LetterFolder": ""
  }, {
   "ID": 3,
   "EntityType": "O",
   "EntityLabel": "Gas",
   "Parent": "Other",
   "MultiplePerCase": false,
   "DynamicOrgID": 0,
   "OrgFKID": 0,
   "OrgID": "",
   "OrgContactID": "",
   "OrgRef": "",
   "DynamicPersonID": 0,
   "PersonFKID": 0,
   "ThirdPartyID": "",
   "PersonRef": "",
   "SectionHeaderID": 0,
   "EntityName": "Gas",
   "AccessLevel": "",
   "LetterFolder": ""
  }, {
   "ID": 4,
   "EntityType": "O",
   "EntityLabel": "Electric",
   "Parent": "Other",
   "MultiplePerCase": false,
   "DynamicOrgID": 0,
   "OrgFKID": 0,
   "OrgID": "",
   "OrgContactID": "",
   "OrgRef": "",
   "DynamicPersonID": 0,
   "PersonFKID": 0,
   "ThirdPartyID": "",
   "PersonRef": "",
   "SectionHeaderID": 0,
   "EntityName": "Electric",
   "AccessLevel": "",
   "LetterFolder": ""
  }, {
   "ID": 5,
   "EntityType": "O",
   "EntityLabel": "Council",
   "Parent": "Other",
   "MultiplePerCase": false,
   "DynamicOrgID": 0,
   "OrgFKID": 0,
   "OrgID": "",
   "OrgContactID": "",
   "OrgRef": "",
   "DynamicPersonID": 0,
   "PersonFKID": 0,
   "ThirdPartyID": "",
   "PersonRef": "",
   "SectionHeaderID": 0,
   "EntityName": "Council",
   "AccessLevel": "",
   "LetterFolder": ""
  }, {
   "ID": 6,
   "EntityType": "O",
   "EntityLabel": "Water",
   "Parent": "Other",
   "MultiplePerCase": false,
   "DynamicOrgID": 0,
   "OrgFKID": 0,
   "OrgID": "",
   "OrgContactID": "",
   "OrgRef": "",
   "DynamicPersonID": 0,
   "PersonFKID": 0,
   "ThirdPartyID": "",
   "PersonRef": "",
   "SectionHeaderID": 0,
   "EntityName": "Water",
   "AccessLevel": "",
   "LetterFolder": ""
  }, {
   "ID": 7,
   "EntityType": "D",
   "EntityLabel": "Purchase & Sale Details",
   "Parent": "Property",
   "MultiplePerCase": false,
   "DynamicOrgID": 0,
   "OrgFKID": 0,
   "OrgID": "",
   "OrgContactID": "",
   "OrgRef": "",
   "DynamicPersonID": 0,
   "PersonFKID": 0,
   "ThirdPartyID": "",
   "PersonRef": "",
   "SectionHeaderID": 0,
   "EntityName": "PurchDets",
   "AccessLevel": "",
   "LetterFolder": ""
  }],
  "PropertyID": 2,
  "LandlordID": 0
 }
}
```

PropertyDetailsViewModel

```
public class PropertyDetailsViewModel
{

    public int PropertyID { get; set; }
    public PropertyDetail PropertyDetail { get; set; }
    public PropertyImages PropertyImages { get; set; }
    public InventoryList InventoryList { get; set; }

    public string PropertyPath { get; set; }

    public SideNavigationViewModel SideNavigationViewModel { get;set;}
}
```

Comment: Please include PropertyDetailsViewModel

Comment: i did, but someone edited it out. ill try add again

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the [FromBody] attribute.

Make your post method look like this:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult SaveDetails([FromBody]PropertyDetailsViewModel PropertyDetail)
{
    if(PropertyDetail != null)
    {

       return Json("Success");

    }
    return Json("Failed");

}
```

Comment: Type or namspace could not be found. ive inclued using System.web.http at the top is that correct?

Comment: Which MVC version are you using and which framework? Yeah the namespace should be System.Web.Http

Comment: Im using MVC 5, RAZOR

Comment: Yeah it should be at System.Web.Http

Comment: I might actually be wrong. There is a chance that you have to code your own form model binder. Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32012288/asp-net-mvc-5-bind-parameter-exclusively-from-body/32012382

Answer (score 0):

I did some more research and found this way of getting it to work, not sure if its the  best solution, but never the less a solution. It works for now.

```
 public ActionResult SaveDetails()
    {

        Request.InputStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
        string jsonData = new StreamReader(Request.InputStream).ReadToEnd();
        PropertyDetailsViewModel PropertyDetail = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<PropertyDetailsViewModel>(jsonData);

        if (PropertyDetail != null)
         {

         return Json("Success");

        }
        return Json("Failed");

    }
```